# Python tox: show stdout/prints on successful test run?

Tags: python, stdout, tox

Sometimes I want to print some statements, to make sure unittests are running fine (even if it passes), but can't find an option that enables it.

If tests fail, then it does show custom prints as output, but if it passes, it does ignore prints or logs (I mean, it dont see them on terminal output).

I tried using verbosity, like `-vvvv`, but it still ignores my prints. With `nose` there is an option like `--nologcapture`. Is there something similar in `tox`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tox as such is just a generic venv creator, deps installer and command executor. It doesn't do output capturing (unless you use [--parallel](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#parallel-mode)). So it is on a different abstraction level from nose. tox can run your tests or anything else that is runnable via command line.

Like you already mentioned for nose: depending on your test runner you might need to deactivate output capturing to see prints coming from the tests. So if you use pytest for example you can use `pytest -s` to disable all output capturing (also see [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html#setting-capturing-methods-or-disabling-capturing))

You can also print something after you ran the test by adding something like this in your `tox.ini` testenv:

```
[testenv:test]
[...]
commands =
    <some test command>
    python -c 'print("All is fine."))'
```